# 'SyntaxError: Invalid shorthand property initializer' when using regex

Tags: javascript, regex, algorithm, visual-web-developer

I'm trying to validate a pin using the following function

```
function validate(num){
  num.length === 4 || num.length === 6 ? {
    regex = /\d+/,
    regex:test(num)
  } 
  :
  false
}
```

however I'm getting this error and I can't figure out why

```
    /home/runner/index.js:3
    regex = /\d+/,
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Invalid shorthand property initializer
```

Comment: Don't try to substitute the conditional operator for `if`/`else`, it's not appropriate - write standalone statements on each line instead, and your code will be much easier to read (and debug).

Comment: @CertainPerformance thanks can you help me with the error though?

Comment: You can't put statements inside object literals.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. You're not doing anything with the result of the conditional expression, is there's supposed to be a `return` statement before it?

Comment: What is `regex:test(num)` supposed to be? Did you mean `regex.test(num)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have pointed out, you can't put statements in conditional expressions (or any other expression, either), you can only put expressions.

The error you're getting is because it thinks you're trying to write an object literal, but you can't have assignments inside object literals.

You can use a normal `if` statement:

```
if (num.length == 4 || num.length == 6) {
    var regex = /\d+/;
    return regex.test(num);
} else {
    return false;
}
```

But there's no need for the conditional at all, you can test the length in the regexp itself.

```
function validate(num) {
    return /^\d{4}$|^\d{6}$/.test(num);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

While I cannot recommend such here, it is important to keep in mind that a [*function expression*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function) can be used in an expression context. This is done all the time, such as for callbacks, and the same concept is transferable elsewhere..

Here is a minimal conversion of the original (which maintains as many of the original's bugs and other features, except where they caused parse errors) showing a function expression. This specific case is also called an ["IIFE"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE).

```
function validate(num){
  return num.length === 4 || num.length === 6
   ? (function() {
       let regex = /\d+/; 
       return regex.test(num);
     })()
   : false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the `?:` operator with statements; only expressions.

However, there is no need to define a variable for your regex here. You can just call `.test` on the regex literal directly:

```js
function validate(num){
  return num.length === 4 || num.length === 6 ? /\d+/.test(num) : false
}
```

Even better, just use the `&&` operator, which is logically equivalent here:

```js
function validate(num){
  return (num.length === 4 || num.length === 6) && /\d+/.test(num);
}
```